# "mark occurrences" does not work in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

After I have switched my IDE from Eclipse Indigo to Eclipse Juno now inside the
Java editor the possibility to mark all occurrences of a marked variable does not 
work any more. It does only work if I explicitly deactivate and activate again the 
proper symbol from the symbol bar. 
Usually that symbol once activated should mark all other variables and when setting the cursor to another variable the same should proceed. I don't want to do these steps
manually by reset the symbol in the symbol bar. What is going on here? Eclipse Indigo
did that without blaming.

Comment: Same problem here, the only thing I can suggest is to remove all plug-ins and try to see if it is happening. There are lots of stability problems with Juno, I think the wikipedia article mentions they are preparing a separate release just for these issues.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is a known issue with Eclipse Juno. I am having this issue with Eclipse Juno 4.2.2

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400661
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398509

**Workaround:** Switch to the Outline view, select something, and switch back to your file again. Mark occurrences should start working again (at least for a little while).

Comment: Thank you very much Victor. I am grateful not being alone with that misbehaviour.

Comment: Your workaround with the outline view doesn't help for me. My workaround is to select the new variable switch to another windows program via alt+tab and switch back and after that the variable occurences are marked.

Comment: I do the following. When switching to the Outline view, I select something in the outline view (like a method or variable) corresponding to the file for which I need "mark occurrences" to work. The downside is that the editor screen will jump to the location of the selected item. So when going back to the editor, I need to get back to the instance that I wanted highlighted.

Comment: I'm using the shortcut "ALT + SHIFT + O", this will toggle the "mark occurences"-mode off and on, highlighting all occurences for the item on the current cursor position. :)
I hope that this prominent feature will be fixed in future Releases.

Comment: Just switching to the Outline view doesn't necessarily work. You have to select something in it.

Comment: @TedHopp You are correct. I updated the answer.

Comment: Will update Juno solve this problem? How can we update the eclipse (or plugin?) to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, this issue is fixed in Eclipse Kepler 4.3

Comment: upgrading eclipse works: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398509#c62

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen.1A here and this bug STILL occurs.